# SE Chat Flagger Bot

Tags: app, python, chatbot

This is a bot that sits in the [MSE tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89). What does it do?

1. Smokey sends in a spam report.
2. You reply `tp` with a reason and it will flag the post accordingly.

## NOTES:

---

This does not flag based on how the post looks, for whether it contains:

> Skin care

It only flags when told to.

TODO:

- Only certain users can tell it to flag

[Github link](https://github.com/TeamFreeHugs/SE-FlaggerBot)

If you want to run it yourself, do this:

[Click here to approve client](https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=5583&scope=write_access,no_expiry&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success)

You will be redirected here on approve:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=1234567890
```

Copy the access token value.

Next create a file `api_details.py` and paste this in:

```
token = '[Token here]'
```

Also create a file `login.json` and paste this in:

```
{"username": "stackexchangeopenid@provider.com"}
```

On bot startup, you will be prompted for a password.

Enter it, and choose to save it or enter it every time you run the bot.